# Regexc - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, regex, segmentation-fault

I'm relatively new to `C` and I have a problem with the following:

```
 regex_t re;
 regmatch_t matches[2];
 int start;
 int end;
 int count = 0;

 int reti = regcomp(&re, "^(?:[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-])*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:\\.(?:[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-])*[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$", REG_EXTENDED);

 while (1) {

   printf("Local = %s\n", local);
   reti = regexec(&re, local, 2, matches, 0);

  // More code here

 }
```

When I run this, I get a `segmentation fault`.

`local` was defined as `char *local` and is being printed out correctly.

I ran the code using `GDB` and it turns out the issue is arising at the line:

```
reti = regexec(&re, local, 2, matches, 0);
```

I can't seem to figure out why.

This is the output from `gdb`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7af8d42 in regexec () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7af8d42 in regexec () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000040092d in email_in (str=0x400aa8 "giri@gmail.com") attestdriver.c:70
#2  0x0000000000400780 in main () at testdriver.c:15
```

Would anyone have any ideas as to what might be the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `regcomp()` and `regexec()`?

Comment: @sunqingyao https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/regcomp.c#L465-L519

Comment: Did you check your `reti` return value to see that `regcomp` actually returns a successful compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually here:

```
int reti = regcomp(&re, "^(?:[a............
```

From [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567118/segmentation-fault-with-complex-regex-regex-h)

> You need to check the return of regcomp, it will tell you that your regex is invalid.
>
> You will get `Invalid preceding regular expression`

`(?:` is not supported by POSIX regexes.

---

It's throwing this error because:

> A common way to get a segfault is to dereference a null pointer

(From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault?rq=1))

The regex cannot initialize because of the illegal `(?:`

The original error is shown in the return of regcomp, and does not halt execution.

Comment: And that produces a segfault? Does the POSIX standard allow that? o.0

Comment: @Siguza: It doesn't segfault on the compilation error, but because an uninitialized `regex_t` is passed to `regexec`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Oh damn, I confused regexec with regcomp in the stack trace. It makes sense now, thanks.